# Are "haff to" and "have to" different words in spoken English?

Tags: english, pronunciation, dialects

This sentence:

> How many apples do you have to eat?

(at least in my dialect of English) means "How many apples do you possess and can eat?" if the final consonant in "have" is voiced (with a "v" sound), and "How many apples are you obligated to eat?" if it's pronounced unvoiced (with an "f" sound). They're the same word in written English, but could they be considered separate words in spoken English?

Comment: We have the same problem with _gonna, wanna, useta, oughta, shouldna,_ and many more. Written English doesn't represent pronunciation, nor does it represent intonation, rhythm, or word or syllable separation. So don't expect much from it. If you want details,  you hafta define "word" better than putting a space after it.

Comment: « You don’t hafta eat apples, ya know. » « No, I do have to. » Obligation, or possession of two apples?

Comment: « How many apples do you *haaave* to eat? »

Comment: "haff to" and "have to" are not different words because "haff"  is not a word.

Answer (score 3):

I found this thread when thinking about the phrase "you have to have", which I would normally pronounce "you haff to have".  I'm a native English speaker and I don't consider this to be a dialect issue.  It seems to be pretty common among people who use grammar and idiom well enough, across multiple regional, social and educational levels.

Edit: So, are they separate words (as per the OP's question)?  IMO, they are are homonyms.  It's a little like the two different pronunciations of "the".  "Thee" (long e) implies a single and significant noun ("she's the best in the whole world") whereas "thu" (short e) implies an indeterminate number ("he's gone to the shops").

In my example, "you have to have it", the first "have (pronounced "haff") denotes an imperative.  The second (pronounced "have") is about ownership.  Two different words, same spelling - classic homonym.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31687)

Answer (score 2):

To the extent that we have any linguistic basis for counting the number of words in English, the best analysis is that "have to" as in "possess, in order to" is two words, and "hafta" is a single word. In the sense of possessing, the verb and following complementizer (or whatever you want to call it) is parallel to other two-word constructions, e.g. "These are all the apples that I {brought/bought/have/carried with me} to eat".

There are also so-called contractions appearing in {oughta, wanna, gonna, hafta} which have paraphrases with verb + "to", which are similar to the same suffix (phonologically) in {coulda, woulda, mighta} paraphraving "have" (hence the spelling "could of"). On phonological grounds, these combinations behave like single words (stress and vowel reduction, flapping, devoicing) as contrasted with the above two-word construction which has a different pronunciation, one indicating that it is made up of two separate words, phrased separately.

Comment: They’re not single words in the same way that ‘BAFTA’ or ‘honour’ (to rhyme with univerbated ‘have to’ and ‘going to’) are, though. Apart from the fact that they can be split back up (‘couldn’ta’, ‘haven’t to’, which doesn’t seem to allow univerbation, etc.), the devoicing to _hafta_ is also facultative in many cases, rather than mandatory.

Comment: I have to agree with Janus. The use of the contraction "hafta" seems to me to be independent of the vocalization of the final consonant. I would say "haff to" as two distinct words unless I'm being intentionally informal (similar to choosing between "going to" and "gonna").

Comment: Is there a verb "haff" different from _have_, or is it just a different verb form, like _has_?

Comment: I would say that the idiomatic sense of 'must' is a single word, like all the other modals. The different pronunciation of hafta or hassta is a giveaway. But when pronounced with a /v/ or a /z/, it's just the verb _have_ as usual, followed by whatever, and it's not a modal.

Comment: The existence of inflections *have to, has to, had to* is another reason not to consider it a single word.

Comment: I have certainly heard plenty of L1 English speakers say things like *ha[f]ing* (modal) which directly contrasts with *ha[v]ing* (possessive) in addition to *ha[f/s]e to*. That would seem like evidence to me that, at least for some speakers, there has been a lexical split.

Comment: @TKR: the inflections are *I haff to, he hass to* and *I have two, he haz two*. But both forms have the same past tense, *I/he had t(w)o*.